# CAKEPHP: Problems with filters

Tags: cakephp, filter

I am trying to apply filters to employees to show them just on the timesheet table. If other code is required to help you help me, I'll start posting it out. The code is filter.ctp

http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/employees

**Problem:** http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/timesheets/filter/19

```
    <table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th><th>name</th><th>Hours</th><th>Employees</th><th>Edit</th>
</tr>

<? foreach($timesheets as $row): ?>
     <tr><td>
<?=$row['Timesheet']['id']?>
</td><td>
<?=$row['Timesheet']['hours']?>
</td><td>
<a href="../../employees/view/<?=$row['employee']['name']?>"><?=$row['employee']['name']?></a>
</td><td>
<a href="edit/<?=$row['Timesheet']['id']?>">Edit</a>
    </td></tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?
class TimesheetsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Timesheets';
    var $scaffold;  
    var $helpers = array('Number');

    function add() {

        //check if user loaded form for first time or had already loaded & is now posting
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            //save the data to the db
            if ($this->Timesheet->save($this->request->data)) {

                //Build message & add to session
                $this->Session->setFlash('Timesheet has been saved');

                //take user back to the index page
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
            //else save did not work
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add Timesheet');            
            }
        }

        //populate the Employee list
        $this->loadModel('Employee');
        $this->set('Employees',$this->Employee->find('list',array('order'=> array('Employee.name'))));
        $this->set(compact('Employees'));       

        //populate the Employee list
        $this->loadModel('Client');
        $this->set('Clients',$this->Client->find('list',array('order'=> array('Client.name'))));
        $this->set(compact('Clients')); 
    }

        //create function to filter Timesheet list by selected Employee
        function filter($Employee_id) {
            $this->set('Timesheets',$this->Timesheet->findAllByEmployeeId($Employee_id));
        }
            //create function to filter Timesheet list by selected Employee
        function filter2($Client_id) {
            $this->set('Timesheets',$this->Timesheet->findAllByClientId($Client_id));
        }


}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set the variable $timesheets on your controller using `$this->set('timesheets', $timesheets)`

Comment: I placed my controller in there, can you spot out where I'd put it; I think I kinda' already have that.

Comment: Oh I see... php variables are case sensitive... you are setting Timesheets and trying to use timesheets

Comment: So they should all be capitalized or lower case?

Comment: It (technically) doesn't matter, but needs to be exactly the same on the Controller and the View. In this case you have one starting with Capital and the other lower case. According to PHP coding standards it should be all lowercase I think